# problem when insert picture + words in table environment

Tags: tables, floats

[image]

I do not know why the words go out of bound (as the picture).
Thank in advanced

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
    \hline
     \centering
   No. &  Pr & Po & Description \\ \hline
    1
    &
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=4.8cm,height=3cm]{Pictures.png}   
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
       \centering
      \includegraphics[width=4.8cm,height=3cm]{Pictures.png} 
    \end{minipage}
    & 
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
       \centering
        $\bullet$ st\ $\bullet$ st.
    \end{minipage}  
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: if you want someone to tell you what is wrong with your code, you need to show the code, preferably a complete small document that shows the problem. Presumably you specified that the table is wider than the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your table is wider than `\textwidth`: (4 x 0.3`\textwidth` = 1.2`\textwidth`)
- instead of use `minipage` you can use `p{...}` column type
- it is not clear, what is content of the last column, I suspect that it is some list

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\setlist[itemize]{nosep=0pt,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                 }
\adjustboxset{width=.25\textwidth,valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
    \hline
No. &   Pr 
        &   Po 
            &   Description         \\ 
    \hline
1   &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}%{Pictures.png}
        &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}%{Pictures.png}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   st.
            \item   st
                \end{itemize}       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]